# docker mongo: lost data in volume folder after copied to another MacBook

Tags: mongodb, docker

On my old MacBook, I used to be working with docker+mongo as following:

`docker run -d -p27017:27017 --name mongo --network mongo-net -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -v mongo-data:/data/db mongo`

by which I was using a folder `./mongo-data` on host system to keep data persistence after mongo restarting.

This was working fine until I need to migrate mongodb to a new MacBook. I copied the folder `./mongo-data`, pulled the latest images and started a container with same command as above, but I couldn't see any data in mongodb. Is there anything wrong or missed?

As a reminder, I have encountered once or twice that the data in mongodb was totally lost after Docker asks for updating on my old MacBook. Is there any clue about this issue?

Comment: `docker run -v mongo-data:...` uses a Docker [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), not a bind-mounted host directory.  `-v $PWD/mongo-data:...` would use a host directory.  The linked Docker documentation has instructions on how to back up and restore the named volume.

Comment: @DavidMaze  thanks for your comment. yes, I should use an absolute path the mongo-data folder. After that, it works as expected. If you would like to put your comment in an answer, I will pick it.